# Jmeter - Throughput shaping timer - sending more requests than expected

Tags: jmeter, throughput

I'm using jmeter throughput shaping timer to send .011 reqs per sec. so I have given Start RPS as .011, end RPS as .011 and Duration as 300 secs. As per my understanding for that duration only 3 requests should happen but it sends 1 request per second.

[ThroughputshapingTimer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0PSf.png)
[Thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZkuW.png)
Expected - 3 hits for 300 secs
Actual - morethan 200 hits per 300 secs duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use FlowActionController if some FTP connections or API calls are made from Pre or PostProcessors.

Answer (score 0):

Throughput shaping timer might not work properly if some connections such as FTP etc are left open when the samplers are done with the execution. Ensure that the connections are being closed. Also, avoid using System.out.println statements in the samplers/postprocessors.